# Copy objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

So I was reading some core concepts in JavaScript Objects:
Here's is a code for copying objects:

```
function copy(a, b) {
    for (prop in b) {
        a[prop] = b[prop];
    }
    return a;
}
```

It'll overwrite the properties of `a` with similar properties o `b`.

Now if i do this:

```
function union(a, b) {
    return copy(copy({}, a), b);
}
```

The book says `union` will use the value from `a` if `a` and `b` have the same properties. Need some clarification.

Comment: `copy({}, a)` will just produce `a`. So `copy(copy({}, a), b)` is the same as `copy(a, b)`

Comment: Throw the book from your window...

Comment: @royhowie No it is not. The OP's code creates a new object, but your version mutates `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The book is wrong, maybe that is a typo.

> will use the value from `a` if `a` and `b` have the same properties.

Since the last call to `copy` pass `b` as the second argument `union` will use the value from `b` if `a` and `b` have the same properties.